# Creating a PHP page to accept a python HTTP POST

Tags: php, python, html

I am attempting to create an agent to collect data and hopefully over HTTP post the file to a webserver running apache2. I am currently using the the following python script to hopefully push the file.

```
import requests
txt = {'file': open('/tmp/pysrv01-20151207-212735')}
post = requests.post('someaddr', files=txt)
```

I understand that possible a simple php page could accept the post and store the file in a directory. Any idea's to something simple and lightweight? Maybe this is a wrong approach.

Comment: `POST` itself is not particularly special when talking about cross-language. In order to accept a `POST` request in PHP you should look at [$_POST](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) the PHP itself should not care where the `POST` request came from, but may have difficulty parsing the string it receives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has documentation for handling file uploads. Start reading here
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

You use the `$_FILE` variable to detect the files included in Python's POST request.  Here's an example given in the PHP doc ...

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was failing however for some key value in $_FILES. Did some more research as managed to get this to work.


`<?php
    $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    if(isset($name)){
        if(!empty($name)){
            $location = '/var/www/html/uploads/';
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                echo 'uploaded';
            }
        }
    }  else {
        echo 'please uploaded';
    }
?>`